# How send the model back to an ASP.NET controller using jQuery in a ASP.NET Razor view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor view that accepts data. I am using a Form but I'm not using the post method as I want to first prompt the User about saving. So I have the save button to fire off a jQuery function whereby I then fire off the controller's save method. In other apps, I would have the Post save method defined in the Html.BeginForm() which fires off the corresponding controller method. But as I wanted to run a modal first, I want to fire off that method myself.

The jQuery pops up a modal for confirmation and upon accepting, I attempt to fire off the call to the controller's save method.

I get "model is not defined" in the console. However, I can reference the model just fine in any of the html helpers in the view.

How do I get reference to that model at this level - in jQuery?

It seems to see it:

[image]

```
$.post("UserProfile/ProcessSaveUserProfile", { userProfileForMaintVM: Model });
```

The Razor view (simplified):

```
  @model GbngWebClient.Models.UserProfileForMaintVM

  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the following errors.")
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.WantEmailNotificationsSwitch)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.WantEmailNotificationsSwitch, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.WantEmailNotificationsSwitch, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.City)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.City, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  }

  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
          <a href='#' type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' 
  onclick=ConfirmSaveProfile();>Save</a>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>

  function ConfirmSaveProfile() {
  $(`<div class="modal fade" id="myModal6" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px;">
               <h4 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to save your changes ?</h4>
               <div class="text-center">
                   <a class="btn btn-info btn-yes6">Yes</a>
                   <a class="btn btn-default btn-no6">No</a>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>`).appendTo('body');

     $("#myModal6").modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });

    $(".btn-yes6").click(function () {
        $("#myModal6").modal("hide");

        // Don't want a callback.
        $.post("UserProfile/ProcessSaveUserProfile", { userProfileForMaintVM: Model });
    });

    $(".btn-no6").click(function () {
        $("#myModal6").modal("hide");
    });

    $("#myModal6").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#myModal6").remove();
    });
}
```

The controller method (simplified):

```
  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessSaveUserProfile(UserProfileForMaintVM userProfileForMaintVM)
    {
       Code to call the web api...           
    }
```

Comment: Please include your form code.

Comment: I need to see the html helpers actually, I'm not sure if .serialize() will be able to map them correctly.

Comment: I added more to what was there. Note: It works fine in that it displays the model data. It's just when I save. In the jQuery, I reference Model. But it states the "model is not defined" at run time. In other apps, I would have the Post method defined in the Html.BeginForm() which fires off the corresponding controller method.. But as I wanted to run a modal first, I then will fire off that method myself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a model where those properties will be bound when you do an ajax POST.

1. But first, I believe you need put an ID/primary key field in your form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    // replace this with your primary key field
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id)

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the following errors.")
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.WantEmailNotificationsSwitch)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.WantEmailNotificationsSwitch, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.WantEmailNotificationsSwitch, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.City)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.City, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserProfileSingleVM.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  }
```

2. Create a model where those properties will be bound to;

```
public class ReceiveModel{
   // replace this with data type and name of your primary key field
   public int Id {get;set;}

   // replace data type if incorrect
   public string Email {get;set;}
   public bool WantEmailNotificationsSwitch {get;set;}
   public string City {get;set;}
}
```

3. Use this in your button click, don't forget to change the IDs of the input fields on the script;

```
$(".btn-yes6").click(function () {
   // replace the selectors below with the id attribute of your input fields
   // replace Id with your primary key field

   var data = {
      Id: $("#Model.Id").val(),
      Email: $("#Model.UserProfileSingleVM.Email").val(),
      WantEmailNotificationsSwitch: $("#Model.UserProfileSingleVM.WantEmailNotificationsSwitch").val(),
      City: $("#Model.UserProfileSingleVM.City").val()
   };

   $.ajax({
      url: 'UserProfile/ProcessSaveUserProfile',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function (data) {
         // ...
      },
      error: function () {
         alert("error");
      }
   });
});
```

4. Then in your controller action, use the ReceiveModel as parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessSaveUserProfile(ReceiveModel model)
{
   // replace with id property
   UserProfileForMaintVM uvm = db.UserProfileForMaintVM.FirstOrDefault(m=>m.Id==model.Id);

   // assign new properties
   uvm.UserProfileSingleVM.Email = model.Email;
   uvm.UserProfileSingleVM.WantEmailNotificationsSwitch = model.WantEmailNotificationsSwitch;
   uvm.UserProfileSingleVM.City = model.City;

   // call your web api then pass uvm 
   db.SaveChanges();          
}
```

Comment: I already have a model in the view. I have about 35 drop downs in the model as well as about 25 main fields. Why do I have to create another? All are hooked up to the htmlhelpers and display just fine. Are they not bound to the model i already have?. I can edit and select data just fine. I have an AJAX post. It's just it cannot find the model in the jQuery. I just don't get why. I tried: var datafromform = $("#Model").val(); I get undefined.

Comment: I only saw 3 fields so I based my answer there. What you could do is during `var data` assignment, put all your properties there. `$("Model".val()` or any reference to `@Model` wont work because `@Model` values are fixed till you submit them. They aren't bound like angular or a client-side framework where you any changes made is automatically reflected.

Comment: Simple test: using the model and a property, I get 'undefined'. var whoIAmDescrModel = $("#Model.UserProfileSingleVM.WhoIAmDescr").val(); Now using the element name: var whoIAmDescr = $("#UserProfileSingleVM_WhoIAmDescr").val(); I get its actual value. So I cannot reference that model at all.